# Jar can't find resources

Tags: java, resources, readfile

So I am trying to load single string from a txt file, so I can simply update resource directory, instead of changing the code.

Application works fine in IDE (IJ),
I also used same approach in other classes.

My concerns are that I am maybe doing something wrong working on Main class, or trying to do that in it's own method.

Other usages were just in class constructor, no methods involved.

I have also tried `getClass()`... approach.

```java
public static String getGameVersion() {
    //return "DayZ SA_v1.19.155390 (18 October 2022)";
    BufferedReader fileReader;
    try {
        fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources\\mapgroupproto\\gameVersionCompatibility"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        return fileReader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}
```

So ↑ build works on line returning hardcoded String. If I swap comment, program works in IntelliJ (displaying loaded String), but jar doesn't launch.

Answer (score 1):

The *file* in `FileReader` means **file**. Not 'an entry in a jar file'. An actual file, therefore, when you write `FileReader` you're done. That is not going to work.

The way to load resources is like so:

```
ClassWeAreIn.class.getResource("foobar.txt");
ClassWeAreIn.class.getResourceAsStream("foobar.txt");
ClassWeAreIn.class.getResource("/foobar.txt");
ClassWeAreIn.class.getResourceAsStream("/foobar.txt");
```

`getResource` returns a `URL`. Various constructors and tools accept these, such as when you want to make an icon in swing. `getResourceAsStream` makes an InputStream, which you must safely close (so, `try (var in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...))` is the right way to do it), which many other things can accept. Such as:

```
try (var resource = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/mapgroupproto/gameVersionCompatibility")) {
  var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  // reader it here
}
```

With a leading slash, it's relative to the root of the classpath entry that contains MyClass. Thus, if you have 1 jar that contains e.g.:

```
jar tvf yourjar.jar

com/yourpackage/yourapp/MyClass.class
com/yourpackage/yourapp/proto/gameVersionCompatibility
```

Then you can read that file with either:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("proto/gameVersionCompatibility");
```

or:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/com/yourpackage/yourapp/proto/gameVersionCompatibility");
```

If ever you're having trouble figuring out where the heck that is looking, print this:

```
System.out.println(MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class"));
```

which works for any class, and will tell you where its looking.

Comment: I think you meant `try (var resource = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream`.